# Endomondo/Strava +iPhone6 +altimeter

Tags: gps, strava

Does anyone know if these work together? I see there are dedicated iPhone +altimeter apps for the iPhone, but I can't find info if there is an altimeter built into the iPhone that works with these Endomondo/Strava apps.

So my fear is that my gps is not tracking the correct altimeter information. Should I be worried?

Comment: Strava deals with this on its help site https://strava.zendesk.com/entries/20965883-Elevation-for-Your-Activity

Comment: The TL;DR of @DWGKNZ 's link is if you're using it for strava it will sort itself out. If your phone has barometric data it will use that, otherwise it will assume you're on the ground and use known elevation values for your location.

Answer (score 0):

GPS *may* be accurate +/- 15 meteres.
http://gpsinformation.net/main/altitude.htm

If you have a GPS device with barometric measurement - then this can improve.

Should you be worried? If you're using it for cycling then probably not - it is only an indicative figure of metres gained or lost.

If you're trying to land a plane - then yes. :)

Comment: LOL great i was just worried the alts i was going up counted!